# The below code snippets produce the same output. But which is right?

Tags: c, pointers, pass-by-reference

The below code snippet is the wrong one.......but seems to work correctly

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fun(char* msg);

int main()
{
    char* str = "Hello";
    printf("%s\n",str);

    fun(&str);

    printf("%s\n",str);
    return 0;

}

void fun(char* msg){
    *msg = "World";

}
```

And now the correct code snippet

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fun(char** msg);

int main()
{
    char* str = "Hello";
    printf("%s\n",str);

    fun(&str);

    printf("%s\n",str);
    return 0;

}

void fun(char** msg){
    *msg = "World";

}
```

***The objective of the above code is to modify the value of str.*** 
Both codes produce the same output but why does the wrong code seems to work correctly in this case.

Comment: When code invokes undefined behavior, then _sometimes_ it seems to "work".  Save time - enable compiler warnings.

Comment: I wouldn't say "seems to" - undefined means undefined, meaning that on specific compilers or systems an operation that is "undefined" does exactly what the author intended

Comment: @GovindParmar this code is actually a *constraint violation*  (2 of them in fact), the compiler must issue a diagnostic message (and any executable produced is meaningless)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first one should not compile, because `&str` is a `char**`, but the function is declared to take a `char*`.

Additionally, in `*msg = "World";`, `"World"` is a `char*` but `*msg` is a single `char`.